# Mapping data points to an interactive map

Tags: python, dictionary, go, web, analytics

I have a chunk of data in HTML and PDF form. I'm researching ways to get that information into an organized CSV file. This part I think I can figure out on my own.

My question is once I accomplish that, my big goal is to plot these data points on a map of the US. How can I go about doing this?
The NYTimes corona virus tracking page https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.htm
does a fabulous job of mapping data.

I would like a dot on a map, and a variety of colors based on what row the data point comes from (hot to cold). With a dataset of a little over 1,000 points is it better to store the information in a database vs. a JSON file? Are there any opensource mapping tools that can help me here?

The final product will not be posted on the web, hosted locally for research purposes.

Comment: Given the small dataset size, store the data in whatever format you find most convenient. Requests for recommendations on tools and libraries are off topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Well it is an off topic question but this might be useful https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/visualization